# Math symbol error in geom_text

Tags: r, math, ggplot2

Inserting a math symbol to the text should not be so complicated I supposed!

OTH, even looking similar examples 
[ggplot2 facet_wrap with mathematical expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044906/ggplot2-facet-wrap-with-mathematical-expression)

still I am not able to insert Ω (Omega) symbol to the `geom_text`!

Suppose you have basic scatter plot and you want to add mean value with (Omega) math symbol to each facet,

```
mean.Petal <- aggregate(iris["Petal.Width"], iris["Species"], mean)
    Species     Petal.Width
1     setosa       0.246
2 versicolor       1.326
3  virginica       2.026

ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Sepal.Width ,col=factor(Species))) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Species)+
  geom_text(data = mean.Petal, parse = TRUE,
            aes(x = 4.5, y = 7, label=sprintf('mean_Petal=%.2f %s', 
                                               round(Petal.Width,digits=2),'Omega')))
```

> Error in parse(text = as.character(lab)) : :1:17: unexpected
>   symbol 1: mean_Petal=0.25 Omega

Another try

```
geom_text(data = mean.Petal, parse = TRUE,
          aes(x = 4.5, y = 7, label=paste('mean_Petal=', 
                                  round(Petal.Width,digits=2),expression(Omega),sep=' ')))
```

> Error in parse(text = as.character(lab)) : :1:18: unexpected
>   symbol 1: mean_Petal= 0.25 Omega

Comment: Following give the Omega symbol.   `geom_text(data = mean.Petal, parse = TRUE,
            aes(x = 2.5, y = 7, label=paste('mean_Petal=', 
                                            expression(Omega), sep=' ')))`

Comment: What is your aim with `round(Petal.Width, digits=2)` ?

Comment: @DiscoSuperfly thanks.  `round(Petal.Width, digits=2) ` I need mean values before the 'omega'. So I need them!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When using `geom_text` with `parse = TRUE`, you want to put together a string that corresponds to a `plotmath` expression, so you can do:

```
ggplot(iris) +
    geom_point(aes(y=Sepal.Length,x=Sepal.Width ,col=factor(Species))) + 
    facet_wrap(~ Species)+
    geom_text(data = mean.Petal, parse = TRUE,
              aes(x = 3, y = 7, 
                  label=paste("'Mean petal' ==", round(Petal.Width, digits=2), "* Omega")))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is I was looking for!